# Почему я получаю ошибку 404 при запуске сервлета в Java на Tomcat?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, tomcat

Установлен Tomcat.
Имеется JSP-страница`index.jsp`, который передает управление сервлету. Сервлет передать значение на другую JSP-страницу с именем `result.jsp`. Почему при нажатии на кнопку, на странице `index.jsp` я получаю `HTTP 404 error`?

**index.jsp**:

```xml
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Time counter</h4>
    <form name="Simple" action="controller" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="time" value="hello"/>
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Calculate time"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот сам сервлет:

```java
@WebServlet("/controller")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    private void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String timeFromJsp = req.getParameter("time");
        req.setAttribute("value", timeFromJsp);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/result.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
}
```

Вот `result.jsp`:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Result</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Value: ${value}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Структура каталогов такая:
[image: Структура проекта]
[image: Сам сервлет]

На всякий случай привожу пример `web.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <!-- MAIN PAGE -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- ERROR PAGE -->
    <error-page>
        <location>/jsp/error/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответа нету, нашёл его сам.

При попытке обращения к сервлету вылетала ошибка 404. И тут я начал задумываться, а всё дело оказалось проще.

Так как я установил Tomcat 10.0.7, то там произошли изменения. Согласно [официальной документации](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html#Specification_APIs), теперь так:

> There is a significant breaking change between Tomcat 9.0.x and Tomcat    10.0.x. The Java package used by the specification APIs has changed from    javax... to jakarta.... It will be necessary to recompile web applications against the new APIs.

А это значит, если ранее в `maven` нужно было подключать `servlet` таким образом:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

То теперь нужно так:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.web/jakarta.servlet.jsp -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Теперь зависимости в Java-классе сервлете будут выглядеть следующим образом:

```java
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
```

Comment: да йошкин кот, никогда бы не подумал, спасибо!